# Excel2Latex column alignment

Tags: tables, excel2latex

I would like to create the following (Excel) table in LaTeX:
[image: Result Excel]

I use the `Excel2Latex` add-on and get the following code (I included adjustbox to scale the table):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}



    \begin{table}[htbp]
      \centering
      \caption{Add caption}
      \begin{adjustbox}{max width=0.77\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{lrrr}
        \textcolor[rgb]{ .635,  .482,  .208}{} & \textcolor[rgb]{ .718,  .353,  .133}{\textbf{One}} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .69,  .314}{\textbf{Two}} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5.625em}}{\textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .439,  .753}{\textbf{Three and Four}}} \\
        \midrule
        This is wat i want to test in latex test test test test test test test test test  & \textcolor[rgb]{ .718,  .353,  .133}{3.5} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .69,  .314}{3.0} & \textcolor[rgb]{ 0,  .439,  .753}{2.0} \\
        \end{tabular}%
        \end{adjustbox}
      \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \end{table}%

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:
[image: Result Latex]

Two things are wrong in the Latex result: (i) The columns are not equally wide ("One", "Two", "Three and Four") and (ii) These cells are not aligned at the bottom right. I tried to change

```
\multicolumn{1}{p{5.625em}
```

to

```
\multicolumn{1}{r}
```

but it does not work. Would be great if somebody could help me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please  post a full compilable code, not just a fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using the `array` package, you could define a new column type which takes a fixed width and aligns the cells to the bottom:

  ```
  \newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}b{#1}}
  ```
- I recommend not to scale elements which contain text, this will result in unfavourable font sizes. You could use a smaller font size instead of wrap the content of the first column like in the following example:

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}b{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabularx}{.77\linewidth}{
        X
        >{\color{red}}R{1.6cm}
        >{\color{green}}R{1.6cm}
        >{\color{blue}}R{1.6cm}
        <{\color{black}}
    }
    \toprule    
    & One & Two & Three and Four \\
    \midrule
    This is wat i want to test in latex test test test test test test test test test  & 3.5 & 3.0 & 2.0 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. One adoption would be necessary: "One", "Two" and "Three and Four" should be equally wide.

Comment: @AssMero Please have a look at my edited code

Comment: Thank you very much - would be great if you could explain that command a little bit: "\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}" Would it be possible to reduce the distance in the header (one, two..) to the lines?

Comment: I tried to add \tiny after \begin{table} - this was OK, except that the font size of the first row was too large. Then I added "\small"l to "\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\small\\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}". Surprisingly, the font size for the whole columns changes (one, two three and four)

Comment: @AssMero I simplified the code a bit. This comes also with less spacing around the header.